# Creating a featured channel entry

Tags: channel-entries, custom-fields, filter

I would like to add channel field checkbox called featured and filter out the entries if it is checked.

Can this be done using the channel entries tag?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible for sure. Follow the steps.

1) create a checkbox field named "featured" and pass the checkbox options i.e, "yes".

2) check the checkbox in entry which you want to set as featured.

3) on fornt-end code of your `{exp:channel:entries}` pass parameter `search:featured="yes"`

This will bring the entries only you checked as "yes" in backend.